# Will a MQ topic persist messages when one of the consumers is down

Tags: interview, message-queue

If I have a websphere MQ topic and 3 listeners have subscribed to the Topic. One listener is down when a message comes in the Topic. Other listeners consume the message. When the listener comes back up, will the message still be there? My gut feel is no, but i cannot say for sure.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a conceptual programming problem and is too old to migrate anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is configurable, not by the topic but by subscriber.  If you subscribe to a topic as a durable subscriber(all you have to do is set a flag and give a unique name) then you get all messages.  Don't forget you have to unsubscribe when done or you have issues where the queue hold on to data forever and explodes. [Relevant documentation.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.xms.doc/concepts/xms_csub_dur.html)